# Is there a better way to add a ton of JPanels with unique images attached to an array?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have an entire deck of cards as images I need to:
a) load in as JPanels and 
b) display in a JFrame.

Is there a better way to get them into my program then over and over (52x) writing something like

```
final JPanel panelName = draw(new ImageIcon("spritesheet.gif"));
```

Each image (spritesheet.gif) has a unique name. It's a deck of cards.

Here is `draw`

```
public static JPanel draw(final ImageIcon img)
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel()
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        //paintComponent is called automatically by the JRE whenever
        //the panel needs to be drawn or redrawn
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            img.paintIcon(this, g, 10, 10);
            }
    };
    panel.setOpaque(false);
    return panel;
}
```

Comment: Use a JLabel with an Icon. See the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Comment: Why a bunch of panels as opposed to a bunch of `JLabel` objects (which can each hold an `ImageIcon` of an `Image`)?

Comment: each image has a unique name. I should have said so in the OP.

Comment: *"each image has a unique name.." `"filename.gif"` should be `"spritesheet.gif"` *"I should have said so in the OP."*  Yes, it pays to have all information at hand, when answering questions.

Comment: But getting back to *"unique name."*  OK they are unique, but is there some sort of pattern to them (e.g. "spades-queen.gif" can be made from an array (`String[]`) of suits, and array of levels, a `-` to separate them & a `.gif` on the end..).

Comment: you can make an enum out of the names too

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson that is really smart. They're formatted like `aceSpades` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> each image has a unique name..

As long as there is some sort of pattern to them it can be easy.  E.G. `"spades-queen.gif"` can be made from an array `String[]` of suits, an array of levels, a `-` to separate them & a `.gif` on the end..

> They're formatted like `aceSpades` and so on.

Here is an implementation:

```
public class CardNames {
    public final static String[] SUITS = {
        "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"
    };
    public final static String[] LEVELS = {
        "ace", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
        "ten", "jack", "queen", "king"
    };
    public final static String SEP = "";
    public final static String XTN = ".gif";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String suit : SUITS) {
            for (String level : LEVELS) {
                System.out.println(level + SEP + suit + XTN);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
aceSpades.gif
twoSpades.gif
threeSpades.gif
fourSpades.gif
fiveSpades.gif
sixSpades.gif
sevenSpades.gif
eightSpades.gif
nineSpades.gif
tenSpades.gif
jackSpades.gif
queenSpades.gif
kingSpades.gif
aceHearts.gif
// ...
aceClubs.gif
twoClubs.gif
threeClubs.gif
fourClubs.gif
fiveClubs.gif
sixClubs.gif
sevenClubs.gif
eightClubs.gif
nineClubs.gif
tenClubs.gif
jackClubs.gif
queenClubs.gif
kingClubs.gif
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I actually implemented this from your previous comment and it works like a charm. I really appreciate it, been banging my head on the wall about this forever.

Comment: Glad I could help, and you can now get on with more fun stuff.  :)